# Theming the navbar in Twitter Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

The Twitter Bootstrap documentation offers no explanation with the following navbar example

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-inverse">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>
```

there is the image output of the above examples biut no explanation on how they actually affects the navbar. Can somebody explain how they work?

Comment: isn't it YOUR documentation?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see using the image example using the documentation <kbd>[**Color schemes**](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#color-schemes)</kbd> each class affects the navbar with a couple of different css attributes. If you need to know which exact styles, you can check this easily by simply trying it out.

Although you could check bootstrap <kbd>[**v4alphas github**](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev/scss)</kbd> page to read through their SCSS files. For example these are changes made using `.navbar-light`:

```
// Dark links against a light background
.navbar-light {
  .navbar-brand {
    color: $navbar-light-active-color;

    @include hover-focus {
      color: $navbar-light-active-color;
    }
  }

  .navbar-nav {
    .nav-link {
      color: $navbar-light-color;

      @include hover-focus {
        color: $navbar-light-hover-color;
      }
    }

    .open > .nav-link,
    .active > .nav-link,
    .nav-link.open,
    .nav-link.active {
      @include plain-hover-focus {
        color: $navbar-light-active-color;
      }
    }
  }

  .navbar-divider {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.075);
  }
}
```